# pattern recognition on user definition for ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to find patterns in data on users defined conditions? how to do that with ELK stack.

Is there any tutorial or book anything which can lead the way would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post an example, so it gives everyone an idea of what the problem at hand is

Comment: I am considering a machine, which is generating type A logs every 30 min that I am alive. Now if any error occurs then error type log will be generated. Now how to set conditions to filter those data and then try to apply a pattern recognition algorithm so we can understand when or what happens when the device stops working.

Comment: Look at Logstash and its abundance of available filters that can parse and insert your logs into Elasticsearch. From there you can use aggregations and queries in Elasticsearch to identify patterns, simple as that.

Comment: is any list of algorithms? what kind of algorithm work on what kind of data